# how to get an input in Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a query, which needs to get an input "user" and then search. My code is:

```
import sys
import pymongo
import re
import codecs

from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()

db = client['moviesdb']

user = input("Enter the user: ")

# #ratings = db.ratings

from bson.son import SON



# import pprint


cursor = db.ratings.distinct("MovieID",{"UserID":"user"});
# curson = db.ratings.distinct("UserID",{"MovieID":{"$in":a}});


for document in cursor: 
    print (document)
```

in the cursor, if I replace "user" with any number like 1 or 2, it works, but if I use "user" like the code above, it does not work.What is the problem? Also, if I have to use two queries to get the result, like the code above(but I comment the second query for now), what should I do?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `"user"` vs `user`

`"user"` is a `str`ing. `user` is an identifier which evaluates to the value of the variable.

Try this:

```
cursor = db.ratings.distinct("MovieID",{"UserID":user}) # notice no quotes on `user`
```

## You need to convert your input to an `int`eger

Try `user = int(input(...))`

Comment: I tried user first, it did not work. Then I tried "user", it still did not work.. So I think it is not because of the quotes

Comment: @user8348955 oops overlooked something. see my edit; try this

Comment: It works now, I do not know why it does not work at first. Thanks

Comment: @user8348955 huh that's pretty strange. But I'm glad it works now! :)